# Phpstorm не подсвечивает методы объекта

Tags: php, phpstorm

Создал класс, внутри класса переменную `$dbh` и присвоил ему `PDO`. Далее обращаюсь к `$this->dbh->` и надеюсь на автокомплит, но редактор не видит методов.

Можно это как-то побороть, или я что-то неправильно делаю?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: в инете я нашел информацию на счет этого. Надо phpDoc добавлять с `@type \PDO` например к свойству `$dbh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [phpDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/) для описания свойств и магических методов

```
/** @var  \PDO */
private $dbh;
```

Answer (score 3):

Нужно указать класс в комментариях:

```
/**
 * @var PDO $dbh
 */
private $dbh;
```

Answer (score 2):

Phpstorm не понимает, какой класс у $dbh. Чтобы 100% понимал добавьте мета-комментарий:

```
/*
@var PDO
*/
private $dbh;
```

Comment: в первой строке 2 звездочки, иначе редактор не видит.

Comment: @Jean-Claude phpshtorm точно видит. Да и netbeans вроде. У них политика - не навязывать определённый синтаксис. Но это получается не по phpDoc - но мне не нравятся жёсткие правила комментирования, поэтому ответ таков.

Comment: у меня phpstorm 2016, с одной звездой не видит. Ну да и ладно.

Comment: @Jean-Claude у меня тоже 2016 - и видит) Может ты прав, может быть у них есть настройка вроде strict PhpDoc - и она у нас разная..